# 2011 Macbook Pro - reinstall OS X in single-user mode?

Tags: macos, usb, install, single-user

I'm working on a friend's 2011 MBP.  It's got the oh-so-common issue of the discrete graphics chip being busted, so GUI is hit and miss (most of the time it misses).

The current installation has been corrupted, and I can't get the GUI installer to run (or maybe I'm not waiting long enough - USB lights tell me that the drive is sleeping, so it's done reading from the USB).

I've got the Mavericks (OS X 10.11.2) install USB, and I need to know how to install OS X in text-only mode, similar to what you could do with Linux installers back in the day (some still support it).

Can I install OS X in text-only mode?

Comment: I'm going out of town in a couple days, so leave a post if you have any input and I'll get back to you sometime after January 2nd or 3rd.

Comment: Have you contacted Apple about fixing it?  Have a look at: [MacBook Pro Repair Extension Program for Video Issues](http://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/)

Comment: I've seen that page, and I'm going to recommend that my friend take it to apple.  The only issue with that is that most people say that the replacement logic board they give you doesn't fix the issue.  I'm hoping that won't be the case, but if it is then I will manually reflow the GPU myself.

Comment: People have said that that works, and while there are companies that will do it for you, it's easier for me to do it myself.

Comment: But back to my question, can I run the OS X installer in text-only mode?